# How to send data from adapter into activity in Android

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-bundle

I want send data from **adapter** into **activity** but without `startActivity`.
I write below codes in **adapter** :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sendDate", model.get(0).getLastSaleDate());
```

And write below codes in **activity** :

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

mainBoxOfficeDate.setText(bundle.getString("sendDate"));
```

Show me this **error** :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6754)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: how to u go activity without startActivity ? does this adapter inside MainActivity (i mean Adapter is called from MainActivity)?

Comment: @msh.nayan, I initialize adapter :         `boxOfficeAdapter = new BoxOfficeAdapter(context, model);`  can you help me?

Comment: model.get(0).getLastSaleDate() have data value?

Comment: boxOfficeAdapter = new BoxOfficeAdapter(context, model); is this adapter is initialize from MainActivity ?

Comment: @sasikumar,  yes, can you help me?

Comment: @msh.nayan , yes

Comment: Use the interface to pass data to MainActivity.

Comment: @Jeeva, I can use interface. but are interface is good way?

Comment: Yes...  Interface always good to use for communicating adapter to activity.

Comment: @Jeeva, thanks my friend, I use interface and fixed! send you answer into other post and I accept it. tahnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Interface:-

```
public interface IMethodCaller{
void yourDesiredMethod(String text);
```

}

Call interface when clicking the button or any action item:-

```
Button btn=(Button)convertView.findViewById(yourButtonId);

btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mContext instanceof IMethodCaller){
        ((IMethodCaller)mContext).yourDesiredMethod();
    }
}
```

});

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

you sent value using Intent instead of  Bundle.so use Intent for receive data in Activity

```
Intent intent=this.getIntent();
if(intent !=null)// to avoid the NullPointerException
 mainBoxOfficeDate.setText(intent.getStringExtra("sendDate"));
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, in your code not show me error, but in textView not set any text! how can I fix it?

Comment: In adapter I show this model.get(0).getLastSaleDate()); into toast and show data ! but in activity show null

Comment: please help me my friend, I really need this help, please

Comment: send data like this....Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sendDate", model.get(0).getLastSaleDate());
context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: This is not the correct solution @sasikumar. this will recreate the activity again.

Comment: then use sharedpreference  for passing data without startActivityhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030276/android-putextra-without-start-activity